# Are my panels wired correctly?

Tags: wiring

[image][image]My 100 amp breaker in my 200 amp main panel that is feeding my 100 amp RV panel arcing very badly and tripping when the break is turned on (but only on one pole). No power is being pulled from the breaker at RV panel (all breakers are off), so not under any load from RV panel. Everything looks right, don't know what is causing it to blow.
I have contacted him but no answer yet. And if not, could the breaker be bad? I have attached picture of both my panels. These have been inspected and bought off by L&I

[image: RV Panel]

Comment: I am trying to add a picture of the main panel but it would only let me load one picture and I don't see how to add on on comments. I will add if I can

Comment: Can you add a picture of the diagram for the 100 amp RV panel?  Those line connections look strange, like they're shorted... maybe a bad picture.

Comment: @jack - I don't have a diagram for 100 amp. It's on the panel at my property. What do you mean by look shorted?

Comment: Those two #3 AWG  line cables  look like they're connected to the same bar.  Probably a bad photo but you did mention tripping a 100 amp breaker in the main panel and that would do it.

Comment: @jack- I thought the same thing. Looked on website and they said the two outside lugs are for a 2nd set of 200amp wires to feed another panel. You can connect them in series. My electrician said to pull wires off breaker and if it still trips/arcs then it's the breaker. If not, something else is wired wrong but said everything looks good. But since there is no load being pulled, it has to be breaker.

Comment: I'd pull the wires off the rv panel... and try the 100 amp breaker again...

Comment: @jack- Yes, agreed. Just spoke with my electrician and he said the same thing. Except just pull them off the breaker and if breaker still trips/arc then breaker is bad. Next check for loose connections and tape any bare wires on receptacles to make sure nothing is touching anywhere, because when the covers goes back on the RV panel it's a tight fit.

Comment: Yes, what you have there is a "ranch panel".  It has 8 spaces presumably for taps to subpanels, and feed-thru lugs to take the entire 200A onward to e.g. the farmhouse. Thus all the breakers and subpanels share the 200A, and the house has access to the full 200A. Once saw someone try to wire a whole house using the 8 spaces available... using tandems actually did make it, but the homeowner was dissatisfied by being out of spaces.  I suggested a 200A 30-space subpanel, but then, we realized the subpanel had *the exact same box* as the ranch panel, so they just switched panel guts and cover.

Answer (score 8):

Read the documentation for your RV stand panel.  It is specifically for RV stands.

One common setup with such stands is to serve multiple stands from one feeder.  For instance 90A feeder serving 2 RV stands or 120A feeder supplying three RV stands.  As such, the RV panels are set up to be "daisy chained".  That means they have two lugs for each pole and neutral - one for supply side and one for onward power to the next RV box.

On yours, there are four hot lugs across the top.
Pole 1 in - pole 2 in - pole 2 out - pole 1 out.  (It doesn't really matter which one is in vs out, they are internally bridged to each other.)

Anyway, you have hooked your supply  L1 and L2 to the center two, which are both pole 2.  Those two lugs are directly cross-connected, as can be seen by the continuous metal between them.  You are creating a dead short.

Move one of the hots to an outer lug.

Comment: @ Harper - Reinstate Monica - are you saying I should have one wire on the inside lug and one on the outside lug coming from main panel? I though the outside lugs are for feeders to another panel.

Comment: @Dean Yes, one on an inside and one on an outside. The confusion is because on an ordinary panel it would be "left/right", not "inside/outside". But an ordinary panel would also have the breakers vertical (with the poles zig-zagging left/right) and here they are horizontal - which makes sense for the standard 50/30/20.  The good part here (unlike in many other places where everything is hidden) is that you can actually see the metal. Check the directions for the panel and you should see it stated pretty clearly - but in any case it is obvious looking at the metal.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving 2 Codidact - I don’t recall getting any instructions with the panel, but I believe there is a schematic on the back of the front cover.. I’ll check it out, but you are right. Those two lugs are clearly are connected

Comment: I can imagine it would arc badly with 100amp poles directly connected :) be thankful your breaker is in working order and trips!!

Comment: "I thought the outside lugs are for feeders to another panel" that's the trouble, you are driven too much by what you *think* and not enough by what you *observe*. (I just had that problem last night myself, spent hours looking for a crankshaft oil seal leak, never thought to check that the timing belt was bone dry).  Also reading the instructions and labeling is mandatory per 110.3(B) which requires you follow them (therefore must read them).

Comment: @ Harper - Reinstate Monica - I did not get any instructions with it. But that aside I fd up badly. Will never happen again. Luckily moving to correct lugs will not be a major issue and it does not appear it affect anything else. I’m hoping it did not fry the breaker. I ordered a new one just in case.

Comment: @Harper - Reinstate Monica - I looked all over online and could not find a wire diagram for this GE RV Panel. If you know where to find one I would like to look at it. I will not be going to my property which is 1.5 hours from my home until next weekend to correct wiring. But just wanted to look at it. I attached a picture showing the underside of the panel lid. It appears to have maybe instructions and diagram, which I clearly missed. I am embarrassed I let this happen, but also thankful nothing worse happen. This is a major lesson learned for me.

Comment: Well, UL requires labeling and/or instructions for anything they list, this is the companion rule to NEC 110.3.  It is possible that UL lists panels with only the labeling on the panel, in which case you must follow that!